# Jenkins pipeline build branch triger

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I have `gitlab` with commit hook to `Jenkins`. The hook is triggered on any commit in any branch. Jenkins has three branches to build. [image: Branches to build]
And I have a problem. If I create any other branch and push it, the hook will trigger the Jenkins and Jenkins will build a branch (master, develop or hotfix) with the newest commit. How can I forbid the build for all other branches except the specified three? I know about `when`, I need to cancel the build, not just one stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an item in the submenu that is responsible for which branches are used to activate the build.
[image]